# Read CSV file from Blob Storage to pandas dataframe and ignore pagination rows from source system

Tags: python, pandas

I have a task which is to read a csv file from blob storage for data manipulation, this is really easy to do:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
blob_client_instance = blobService.get_blob_client(
    "testflorencia", "TakeUpStores.csv", snapshot=None)

downloaded_blob = blob_client_instance.download_blob()
blob = downloaded_blob.content_as_text(encoding=None)
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(blob))
df
```

However I get this error:

```
initial_value must be str or None, not bytes
```

I am not able to share the file here because its confidential, but what I did notice is that every 20 rows there is a special pagination row with a special character:

```
 = 37.364.304;;;; --> special character not rendered by StackOverflow
```

How can I read this csv into pandas and ignore those rows?

I also tried without encoding parameter and I got adifferent error

```
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 16515: invalid continuation byte
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all your special pagination rows are starting with the same single character, then you can make use of the [`comment` parameter](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

> **comment** str, optional

> Indicates remainder of line should not be parsed. If found at the beginning of a line, the line will be ignored altogether. This parameter must be a single character. Like empty lines (as long as `skip_blank_lines=True`), fully commented lines are ignored by the parameter header but not by skiprows. For example, if `comment='#'`, parsing `#empty\na,b,c\n1,2,3` with `header=0` will result in `‘a,b,c’` being treated as the header.

```
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(blob), comment='=')
```

or depending on the first character of the pagination row:

```
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(blob), comment=' ')
```

Answer (score 3):

Filter out the special rows from the downloaded text, then feed it to Pandas.

```
# ...
blob = downloaded_blob.content_as_text(encoding=None)
lines = "\n".join(line for line in blob.splitlines() if not line.startswith(" = "))  # or whatever is the criteria for a special row
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(blob))
```